# Wait for multiple observable ajax calls to finish

Tags: reactjs, redux, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

Using redux-observables in a React Native project, I am trying to make an ajax call to retrieve an array of messages. Once this call has finished I want to make a separate Ajax call for each item in the array, wait for all of them to finish, and then post them using a redux action.

I have *tried* using forkjoin but I'm struggeling to turn the array into an array of observables *(which i think is a necessary step?)* and create the seperate Ajax calls and then wait for them to finish. Is this even possible?

```
export const messagesEpic: Epic = (action$, state$) =>
    action$.pipe(
        ofType('MESSAGES_FETCH'),
        mergeMap((_: Action) =>
            constructAPICall(
                state$,
                'GET',
                api.endpoints.messages('type', 0),
            ).pipe(
                map(response => < insert transform array to observables and ajax -> wait for all to finish >,
                    catchError(error => of({
                        type: GENERAL_API_ERROR,
                        payload: error.xhr.response,
                        error: true,
                    }))
                )))
    );
```

The array that's received on the first ajax call is a simple json array with plain objects that contain an id and other information.

Comment: It's very hard to understand, can you try to explain better your issue ?

Comment: How does your response object look like? What is the name of the service for the second (seperate) ajax calls?